# Переход по роутам как в социальной сети VK на React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-hook

Хочу сделать переходы по роутам как в VK - при нажатии на роут, предыдущий компонент не размонтируется, а ждет пока следующий загрузится и только потом размонтируется и сразу показывает готовый следующий компонент. Пробовал через хук useTransition и тег . Чего-то ничего не выходит.

UPD:
Для этого я сделал так:
Сделал HOC для тега , написал e.preventdefault, передал в колбеке функцию которая будет сделана после запроса на сервер через redux.